# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API + aks + Application Gateway not working together

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-aks, webapi, azure-application-gateway

I've been struggling for two weeks now. So, any help is welcome.
I created an AKS and I tried to host my apps there.

What is done:

1. All the containers are tested locally and working perfectly.
2. All CI/CD are done properly
3. The main services exposed to internet are frontend (Angular 13) and ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
4. The frontend is working properly using tls (without certificate for now). I can access it with no problem using a host url. Exposed using ingress on the app gateway.
5. The problems starts :) The Web API pod is running. I can access it using the load balancer + static ip (kubernetes service type LoadBalancer). But I'm unable to expose it using ingress on the app gateway.

No errors on my pod when I run a kubectl logs podname

The Web API ingress is a copy/paste of frontend api (may be the mistake)

Final thing: when I change the api service to LoadBalancer type, I can access the api from outside using the load balancer.

I believe something's wrong in my ingress definition

Here the two ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "testapi.url.ca"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: api-svc
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: url-tls
      hosts:
        - test.url.ca
        - test.url.com
  rules:
  - host: "test.url.ca"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

My api service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-svc
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    app: api
  ports:
  - name: regular
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

Finaly the docker file to create the image:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 443/tcp

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ./Lib/Contract ./Lib/Contract
COPY ./Lib/Framework ./Lib/Framework
COPY ./Output/Api ./Output/Api

WORKDIR /src/Output/Api
RUN dotnet restore Api.csproj --disable-parallel
RUN dotnet build Api.csproj --no-restore -c Release

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Api.csproj --no-restore --no-build -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/SensitiveData/localhost1.pfx /https/localhost1.pfx
COPY --from=publish /app .

RUN ls -l /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

Thank for your help

I tried different Microsoft tutorials with no success.

I also tried to use the kubernetes ingress but i faced other problems and i decided to come back to my path.

Comment: You might try modifying the ingress definition for the Web API to include a different set of annotations, or to ensure that the correct service and port are specified for the backend.

Comment: Already did. I tried many different annotations. With and without ssl.